# Analysis Limit Proofs

Tags: real-analysis, limits, examples-counterexamples, absolute-value

I am confused on how I would prove the following:

> Prove if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ exists, $\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=|L|$. Also, show there is a function where $\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=|L|$ but $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist.

I really have no idea how to prove either. Any suggestions on how to begin?

Comment: Have you tried using the fact that $\vert \vert x \vert - \vert y \vert \vert \le \vert x - y\vert$?

Comment: The part after "also" is easy: Pick any function that approaches $5$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from above and approaches $-5$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from below. Then the limit as $x$ approaches $a$ does not exist, but the limit of the absolute value does exist and equals $5. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. $\lvert x\rvert$ is a continuous function.
2. Think of a sequence with terms alternatively positive and negative : $(-1)^n u_n$.

Comment: Hint 1 is probably not what is needed.  Circular.  The requested fact is perhaps used in the proof that $|x|$ is continuous.

Comment: This depends on what the O.P. is supposed to know.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$, you want to prove that $\lim_{x\to a}\bigl|f(x)\bigr|=|L|$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. You know that there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-L\bigr|<\varepsilon$. But $\bigl||f(x)|-|L|\bigr|\leqslant\bigl|f(x)-L\bigr|$. Therefore, $|x-a|<\delta\implies\bigl||f(x)|-|L|\bigr|<\varepsilon$.

On the other hand, if$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\in\mathbb Q\\-1&\text{ if }x\notin\mathbb{Q},\end{cases}\end{array}$$then $\lim_{x\to0}\bigl|f(x)\bigr|=1$, but $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: I think you’ve misplaced a few $\vert$’s here and there.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Thanks. I think I corrected them all.

Comment: Yes, I think you have.

Comment: Ok..this makes sense. So basically you use definition of limit/converging and also the triangle inequality?

Comment: @Liza Yes, that's it.